# Connect to Oracle database from PHP with OCI Dockerfile

Tags: php, docker, dockerfile, oci8

I created an application in React and PHP and it works from my computer but I have to dockerize it and move it to a server. When I dockerized the php part it doesn`t connect to the database (oracle). Can someone please give me a Dockerfile for php 7.1 with oci ? Thanks

This is my dockerfile

```
FROM php:7.1.30-apache-stretch

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    unzip \
    libfreetype6-dev \
    libjpeg62-turbo-dev \
    libmcrypt-dev \
    libpng-dev \
    libaio1 \
&& docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) iconv mcrypt gettext \
&& docker-php-ext-configure gd --with-freetype-dir=/usr/include/ --with-jpeg- 
 dir=/usr/include/ \
&& docker-php-ext-install -j$(nproc) gd

 RUN curl -L https://raw.github.com/adrianharabula/php7-with-oci8/master/docker-php.conf -o /etc/apache2/conf-enabled/docker-php.conf

 RUN printf "log_errors = On \nerror_log = /dev/stderr\n" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php-logs.ini

RUN a2enmod rewrite

RUN cd /tmp && curl -L https://raw.github.com/adrianharabula/php7-with- 
 oci8/master/instantclient/19.3.0.0.0/instantclient-basiclite-linux.x64-19.3.0.0.0dbru.zip 
 -O
RUN cd /tmp && curl -L https://raw.github.com/adrianharabula/php7-with- 
 oci8/master/instantclient/19.3.0.0.0/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-19.3.0.0.0dbru.zip -O
RUN cd /tmp && curl -L https://raw.github.com/adrianharabula/php7-with- 
 oci8/master/instantclient/19.3.0.0.0/instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-19.3.0.0.0dbru.zip -O

RUN unzip /tmp/instantclient-basiclite-linux.x64-19.3.0.0.0dbru.zip -d /usr/local/
RUN unzip /tmp/instantclient-sdk-linux.x64-19.3.0.0.0dbru.zip -d /usr/local/
RUN unzip /tmp/instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-19.3.0.0.0dbru.zip -d /usr/local/

RUN ln -s /usr/local/instantclient_19_3 /usr/local/instantclient
# fixes error "libnnz19.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory"
RUN ln -s /usr/local/instantclient/lib* /usr/lib
RUN ln -s /usr/local/instantclient/sqlplus /usr/bin/sqlplus

RUN echo 'export LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/local/instantclient"' >> /root/.bashrc
RUN echo 'umask 002' >> /root/.bashrc

RUN echo 'instantclient,/usr/local/instantclient' | pecl install oci8-2.2.0
RUN echo "extension=oci8.so" > /usr/local/etc/php/conf.d/php-oci8.ini

RUN echo "<?php echo phpinfo(); ?>" > /var/www/html/phpinfo.php

EXPOSE 80
COPY . /var/www/html/
```

Can someone please provide me a simpler Dockerfile just to connect to an oracle database that is on another machine than the server that the app is running.

Thanks

Comment: See https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python-part-1 which shows how to build dockerfiles, and has links to various sources such as some prebuilt images.  Whichever solution you use, please use a more recent version of Instant Client.  The current version is 19.13.

Comment: Are you using `wallet`?